# Is there any way or trick to get just the visible content of the overflow set to hidden in javascript css?

Tags: javascript, iframe, overflow, hidden

I am using a *div* around an iframe and I set the overflow to hidden in the css for *div*
The content is clipped.

I am wondering, is there any way to the get just the visible content?

Here is the code:

```
  <div class="problemBox">
      <iframe id="problem" src="child.html"></iframe>
  </div>

<style>
  .problemBox {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .problemBox iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get the visible content"? Take a snapshot of the page?

Comment: Why don't you just set the width and height of the iframe to 300px?

Comment: Thank you Bergi.                                                                                                 "get the visible content" -> get the text of the visible area. If would have been nice if I can set the height and width of the iframe to 300px. But the current API is designed such, so I cant do much about that